# Why does the VBA Macro code fail when Copying and Pasting from range into new range?

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet onto a different worksheet after identifying the cell value on the worksheet I'm PASTING TO by the date that matches a cell on the COPY FROM worksheet. The macro works when I run it from the PASTE TO worksheet ('Daily Summary Record') but does not work if I run it from another worksheet. I want to be able to run it from any sheet in the workbook, but especially from the PASTE FROM worksheet.

Below is my code:

```
'Daily Itemized')

Sub ArchiveWeek()

    Set thisMon = Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("F5") 'Assigns variable thisMon as the date value in Daily Itemized Tab, F5 cell
        
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
     
    Set ws = Worksheets("Daily Summary Record")
    Set FoundCell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=thisMon, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'PROBLEM. Supposed to: Selects the cell to the adjacent right of the cell in column D with the same date as the Itemized F5 cell
        Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("G5:S11").Copy  'Works to copy range on Daily sheet
        FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'reselects the cell to right of FoundCell
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'works!
        MsgBox ("Your week time values have been pasted!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("The Date of " & thisMon & " was not found in the Daily Summary Record, Column D. Recheck values.")
    End If
    
End Sub
```

See attachments for images of the two worksheets:

'Daily Itemized'

[image: 'Daily Itemized']

'Daily Summary Record'

[image: 'Daily Summary Record']

Comment: I should add, I'm a very novice VBA coder. I've only really just expanded past using the macro recorder to writing original code, so baby steps are appropriate...And I'm entirely self-taught.

Comment: Option number 1 above worked!  So thank you!

Comment: When I tried option #2 I got a debug error on this line of code:

Comment: sorry, it won't let me edit my last comment.  This line of code: FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(7, 13).Values = _
                    Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("G5:S11").Values

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `Select` (and `Selection` and `Activate`) wherever possible:

```
Sub ArchiveWeek()
    Set thisMon = Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("F5") 'Assigns variable thisMon as the date value in Daily Itemized Tab, F5 cell

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Daily Summary Record")
    Set FoundCell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=thisMon, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        'Copy range on Daily sheet
        Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("G5:S11").Copy
        'Paste it on the summary sheet commencing one cell
        ' to the right of the location of the date
        FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        MsgBox ("Your week time values have been pasted!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("The Date of " & thisMon & " was not found in the Daily Summary Record, Column D. Recheck values.")
    End If
```

---

Also, because you are only wanting to copy values, you could improve your code by by-passing the clipboard (with all the associated risks of the user copying something else to the clipboard between when your code executes the `Copy` and when it executes the `Paste`) and just setting the `Values` in the destination area to be the `Values` in the source area:

```
Sub ArchiveWeek()
    Set thisMon = Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("F5") 'Assigns variable thisMon as the date value in Daily Itemized Tab, F5 cell

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Daily Summary Record")
    Set FoundCell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=thisMon, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        'Copy values from Daily sheet to Summary sheet, commencing
        ' one cell to the right of the location of the date
        FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(7, 13).Value = _
                    Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("G5:S11").Value
        MsgBox ("Your week time values have been pasted!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("The Date of " & thisMon & " was not found in the Daily Summary Record, Column D. Recheck values.")
    End If
```

Comment: While this might present as better coding practice, I believe it would make the resulting code un-maintainable by the end-user in this case.

Comment: @mikemorris - I'm curious - which bit will be harder to maintain?

Comment: If the user is used to using .Select in their practice (probably from relying on macro-recorder), asking them to change this approach would substantially alter their workflow / coding-experience, imho

Comment: @mikemorris - The trouble with `Select` is that the code is going to be used by people other than the OP (judging by the task being performed).  Those other people are likely to do things that will break the code if the code relies on a particular sheet being the "active" one.  They get bored, they flick between windows, they accidentally click on something in the current sheet.  They do all sorts of things.  So, yes, there is a learning exercise there for the OP, but it is one that he/she needs to learn at some stage or else they will spend all their time debugging user problems.

Comment: @YowE3K spot on. great advice.

Comment: I should add, I'm a very novice VBA coder. I've only really just expanded past using the macro recorder to writing original code, so baby steps are appropriate...

Comment: Option #1 worked.  Thanks!  Option #2 did not because of this line (debugging error): FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(7, 13).Values = _
                    Worksheets("Daily Itemized").Range("G5:S11").Values

Comment: @mbahonen - DOH!!  `.Values` should be `.Value` - I will edit the answer

Comment: No worries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post. You cannot Select cells from an inactive worksheet. That is why it only works when you're on the PASTE TO worksheet.

To remedy this problem, please consider making this small change to your code:

```
    ...
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    ws.Select
    ...
```

This should make sure the PASTE TO worksheet is activated before the rest of your code executes.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try this as well, although I've already updated my code for the first answer above.